# WARNING: ROS_MASTER_URI [http://localhost:11311] host is not set to this machine' and nodes 'Couldn’t find an AF_INET address for [localhost]'

Tags: master, ros-kinetic, network, ros-master-uri, nodes

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have been running ros nodes in my machine but suddenly I got these erros every time when I'm running nodes:
Master:

```
$roscore
(stuff about the starting of the master)
SUMMARY
PARAMETERS
*/rosdistro: kinetic
*/rosversion: 1.12.12
NODES
WARNING: ROS_MASTER_URI [http://localhost:11311] host is not set to this machine
auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pi [5233]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://182.168.1.90:11311/
etc.
Any node:
Couldn’t find an AF_INET address for [localhost]
Couldn’t find an AF_INET address for [localhost]
ERROR [1519245068]: [registerPublisher] Failed to contact master at [localhost:11311]. Retrying
Couldn’t find an AF_INET address for [localhost]
Couldn’t find an AF_INET address for [localhost]
Couldn’t find an AF_INET address for [localhost] ...
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284130/problem-running-nodes,-master-have-%27warning:-ros_master_uri-%5Bhttp://localhost:11311%5D-host-is-not-set-to-this-machine%27-and-nodes-%27couldn%E2%80%99t-find-an-af_inet-address-for-%5Blocalhost%5D%27/) by [mrght](https://answers.ros.org/users/33942/mrght/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-03-01**:
Is there an entry in `/etc/hosts` for localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you running ROS on multiple machines?
Probably this might be a network problem. See ROS network setup for more information. Also, check your bashrc file and see whether it is properly configured for your ip.

Check you host name using

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

For example:

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME=136.159.101.186 
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://136.159.101.186:11311
```

---

Originally posted by [Gayan Brahmanage](https://answers.ros.org/users/26769/gayan-brahmanage/) with karma: 929 on 2018-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-03**:
If you're going to be using IPs, then use `ROS_IP`, not `ROS_HOSTNAME`.